# How to UV map and image texture to a bezier curve crescent?

Tags: texturing, uv, bezier-curves

I'm new to blender, so apologies if this is a fairly beginner question.
I followed this tutorial ( https://youtu.be/vS1eDp3az5Y ) to make a crescent moon shape using bezier curves. Now, though, I want to UV Map an image texture on top of it, but I can't because there are no real verticies, it's just two bezier curves. Is there any way I can unwrap something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In recent version of Blender, you can use an automatically generated UV Map.  You can modify the map's coordinates in the Properties Editor's *Curve Properties* tab; in the *Texture Space* panel:

[image: properties editor showing texture space panel]

Here is an example material where I just used the automatic map and a generated UV grid image:

[image: sample material using the UV Map]

and here is sample curve:

[image: curve showing uv grid]

You can read more about [Texture Space](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/uv/uv_texture_spaces.html#texture-space) in the manual.